# pythonで質的変数→量的変数（ダミー変数化）

Tags: python

以下に示したようなデータリストがあります。
列見出しは `data1,data2,data3`、行見出しは `A,B,C,...M` として、以下のようなダミー変数を作りたいです。

Pythonを使ってどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

---

**データリスト**

```
data1＝["A","B","C","D","E"]
data2＝["A","B","G","H","I"]
data3＝["A","J","K","L","M"]
```

**ダミー変数**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

カラムは `string.ascii_uppercase` から作成しています。この場合、`data1`, `data2`, `data3` には含まれていない `F` も結果に含める事ができます。

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

data1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
data2 = ["A", "B", "G", "H", "I"]
data3 = ["A", "J", "K", "L", "M"]

pd.DataFrame(
  [Counter(x) for x in (data1, data2, data3)],
  index=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
  columns=list(ascii_uppercase)[:13],
  dtype='Int64'
).fillna(0)

=>
       A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
data1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
data2  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
data3  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

pandas を使って DataFrameを作成し、変換することで

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
data2 = ["A","B","G","H","I"]
data3 = ["A","J","K","L","M"]

df = pd.DataFrame([data1,data2,data3], index=['data1','data2','data3'])
df = df.apply(lambda row: row.value_counts(),axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
#       A  B  C  D  E  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
#data1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#data2  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
#data3  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
```

のように実現できます。

ただし、上記の方法は data1,data2,data3 が同サイズの時しか使えません。

data1,data2,data3 のサイズが違う場合はそれぞれのデータでDataFrameを作成して結合すると実現できます。

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
data2 = ["A","B","G","H","I"]
data3 = ["A","J","K","L","M"]

datas = [pd.DataFrame(1, columns=d, index=[n]) for d,n in zip([data1,data2,data3], ['data1','data2','data3'])]
df = pd.concat(datas).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
#       A  B  C  D  E  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
#data1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#data2  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
#data3  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
```

Series使っても書けますが、コード量的にはあまり変わりませんね。

```
datas = [pd.Series(1, index=d, name=n) for d,n in zip([data1,data2,data3], ['data1','data2','data3'])]
df = pd.concat(datas, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int).T
print(df)
#       A  B  C  D  E  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
#data1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#data2  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
#data3  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

既に解決済みですが、別解です。ライブラリは使っていません。

**コード**

```
data1 = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
data2 = ["A","B","G","H","I"]
data3 = ["A","J","K","L","M"]
row_heading = list(map(lambda x: chr(x),list(range(ord("A"),ord("M")+1))))
out_1 = [(1 if x in data1 else 0) for x in row_heading]
out_2 = [(1 if x in data2 else 0) for x in row_heading]
out_3 = [(1 if x in data3 else 0) for x in row_heading]

print(row_heading)
print(data1)
print(out_1)
print(data2)
print(out_2)
print(data3)
print(out_3)
```

**結果**

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['A', 'B', 'G', 'H', 'I']
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['A', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```